# Ошибка StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: исключения, java

Еще раз здравствуйте.
Допер до того, что для начала нужно  найти строку с цифрами.
Делаю проверку и распечатываю, но вдруг падает на вот такой ошибке:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at TestingColor.fillCollection(TestingColor.java:61)
    at TestingColor.main(TestingColor.java:19)
```

Код:

```
for(int i= 0; i<stringList.size(); i++)
{
   if(Character.isDigit(stringList.get(i).charAt(i)))
     {
       System.out.println("Name" + " " + stringList.get(i));
     }else
     {
       System.out.println("Number" + " " + stringList.get(i));
     }
}
```

Подскажите, в чем проблема.

Comment: @tarasula, как переводится "String index out of range"?

Comment: @tarasula, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

```
public class StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
extends IndexOutOfBoundsException
```

> Thrown by String methods to indicate
> that an index is either negative or
> greater than the size of the string.
> For some methods such as the charAt
> method, this exception also is thrown
> when the index is equal to the size of
> the string.

[Взято отсюда](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) (первая ссылка в гугле)

Comment: Это понятно. Только размер моего листа намного больше (18)

Comment: @tarasula тут нет телепатов. Код. Дай код.

Comment: код уже есть, и я даже в своем ответе объяснил, почему оно там не работает.

Для тех, кто ещё не понял. В списке stringList в пятой строке (с индексом 4) строка содержит меньше 5 символов. Что вполне возможно, так как там, к примеру, может быть одна цифра.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в этом куске кода `charAt(i)`.
Так строка в `i` строке может быть короче, чем `i`. Символа с нужным индексом нет, вот и получаете. Скорее всего, там нужен ещё один цикл либо правильный код.

Answer (score 0):

Как уже написал [@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim), надо 2-а цикла вместо одного. Первый цикл пробегает по строкам в списке, а внутренний цикл должен пробежать по каждому char в строке. Т.е:

```
for(int i= 0; i<stringList.size(); i++)
{
for(int u=0; u<stringList.get(i).lenght(); u++)
{
if(Character.isDigit(stringList.get(i).charAt(u)))
 {
   System.out.println("Name" + " " + stringList.get(i));
 }
else
 {
   System.out.println("Number" + " " + stringList.get(i));
 }
}
}
```